# dateTime without time in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

I am beginner.
I created a webform application. I use entity Framework and view Models.
I have many dateTime entities, but I would like to keep date without time. 
An example:

`<span><%#: (Item.DateNextVisit.HasValue ? Item.DateNextVisit.ToString() : string.Empty) %> </span>`

result : 16/11/2021 00:00:00

How to keep just date in my span tag?

I already try to add "ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" or replace with "ToShortDateString()". but it doesn't work.
Maybe it's not the good place to declare it. But I don't want to declare this in code behind.
Is it possible to just add a property in aspx tags, in the condition?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

Based on the `HasValue` property you are using, `Item.DateNextVisit` is not a `DateTime`, it's a [`Nullable<DateTime>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.7.1).

The `Nullable<T>` struct does not have and overload of the `ToString()` method that accepts a string as a parameter. It only has a parameter-less `ToString()` that returns the text representation of the value of the current `Nullable<T>` object.
Use `Item.DateNextVisit.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` instead.

To put it in context of the code you provided:

```
<span><%#: (Item.DateNextVisit.HasValue ? Item.DateNextVisit.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : string.Empty) %> </span>
```

Comment: or `Item.DateNextVisit.Value.ToShortDateString()`

Comment: @TimSchmelter If you want to return a culture-specific string representation then yes. If you want a specific format, I wouldn't go with anything that might be effected by culture.

Comment: Thank you very much! it works perfectly! :D 
Indeed it's Nullable<DateTime>

Comment: `Item.DateNextVisit?.ToString(..)` would also work. It would return `null` if `DateNextVisit` was null. `Item.DateNextVisit?.ToString(..) ??""` to return empty

Comment: @ZoharPeled: your approach is also culture specific(noticable f.e. if you use `yyyy-MMM-dd`). I've just mentioned because OP also tried to use it. He could also use `Item.DateNextVisit.Value.ToString("d")`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I accept your correction. Explicit format can be culture specific as well.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Correct, though that requires at least c# 6 (vs 2015).

Comment: Methods of Tim and Zohar work, but not the last. It says that I have a old c# version. But thank you for your idea :)

Answer (score 0):

i appriciate your efforts for choosing .Net family.

Use the following format :

```
String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", Item.DateNextVisit);
```

Follow this link to play further with datetime in .Net:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

and thumbs up for the answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If `DateNextVisit` is a `Nullable<DateTime>` you can use the null-conditional operator `?.` to get at the value or return a null. You can also use the null coalescing operator `??` to return an empty string if the value is null :

```
Item.DateNextVisit?.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") ?? ""
```

Eg :

```
<span><%#: Item.DateNextVisit?.ToString("YYYY-MM-DD")??"" %> </span>
```

If DateNextVisit is null, the `?.` operator will return null insted of calling `ToString()`. `??` will replace this with the empty string